# Not getting Symfony error messages with Laravel on Vagrant

Tags: laravel-4, vagrant, symfony-components

I don't seem to be getting the familiar symfony error messages I used to when I wasn't running on a VM. The error message I get when there is a Laravel related issue is a "Whoops, looks like something went wrong" in a white background.

Is there a common solution to this/others run into this problem who can help out?

thanks

Comment: You need to turn $debug to true.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange you can put that as the answer, ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn `$debug` to `true` in `app/config/app.php`